# HTML table rowspan strange behavior

Tags: html, html-table

I have the following html code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="4">1 Rowspan=4</td>
            <td rowspan="3">2 Rowspan=3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4 something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5 something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6 something</td>
            <td>7 something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>8 something</td>
            <td>9 something</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It behaves like this:

[image]

This is wrong! There should be only 2 columns!

I want to have cell #3 below #2 and #4 below #1.

Why isn't that possible?

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FvY5b/

Comment: If every cell in a row spans multiple rows, then something is wrong with your structure.

Comment: Your rowspan serves no purpose in this context. Remove it and use CSS to determine the cell's height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The markup violates the HTML table model. If check the markup with http://validator.w3.org in HTML5 mode, it reports an error: “A table row was 3 columns wide and exceeded the column count established by the first row (2).”

So as suggested in @Aditi’s answer and Madara Uchiha’s comment, change `rowspan="4"` to `rowspan="2"` and remove `rowspan="3"` and set the height of the first row in CSS (as the obvious intent is to make it higher than it would otherwise be).

Answer (score 1):

Try this for the first two rows...

```
<tr>
        <td rowspan="2">1 Rowspan=4</td>
        <td>2 Rowspan=3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
            <td>4 something</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3 something</td>
        </tr>
```